# i am trying to run my web application (java springboot ) has a cassandra db and i keep getting this error

Tags: java, cassandra

`[INFO] BUILD FAILURE Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.1.0:run  (default-cli)`your text` on project myproject: Process terminated with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following
articles
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

i was exepecting it to run on localhost`

Comment: We would need the full error stack. You expressed here the symptom, not the root cause.  Also, where is cassandra running .. in a docker container close to the application ?